# How we apply parent class with odd even logic

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, logic

Please let me know how can I apply CSS odd even logic only for each first parent section element. I want to apply the dynamic odd even class only for the parent section.

```
<section>
     <section>
          <section>
               <section>
                
               </section>
          </section>
     </section>
</section>
<section>
     <section>
          <section>
               <section>
                
               </section>
          </section>
     </section>
</section>
<section>
     <section>
          <section>
               <section>
                
               </section>
          </section>
     </section>
</section>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have shared my opinion :

without class name  :
Link : https://jsfiddle.net/htorxek4/

with class name :
Link : https://jsfiddle.net/n4djyu31/

Html Code :

```
     <section>
     <section>
          <section>
               <section>
                1 section
               </section>
          </section>
     </section>
</section>

    <section>
         <section>
              <section>
                   <section>
                    2 section
                   </section>
              </section>
         </section>
    </section>
    <section>
         <section>
              <section>
                   <section>
                    3 section
                   </section>
              </section>
         </section>
    </section>
    <section>
         <section>
              <section>
                   <section>
                    4 section
                   </section>
              </section>
         </section>
    </section>
```

Css Code :

```
section:nth-child(odd) {
   background: red;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
   background: lightgreen;
}
section section {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for parent container

```
    <section class="parent">
         <section>
              <section>
                   <section>
                    
                   </section>
              </section>
         </section>
    </section>
    <section class="parent">
         <section>
              <section>
                   <section>
                    
                   </section>
              </section>
         </section>
    </section>
    <section class="parent">
         <section>
              <section>
                   <section>
                    
                   </section>
              </section>
         </section>
    </section>
```

and the apply this style

```
.parent:nth-child(odd) {
     // CSS properties for odd
 }
        
 .parent:nth-child(even) {
       // CSS properties for even
  }
```